# How can I set the canvas background before downloading

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, html5-canvas

I am creating a drawing app, and using this function to download the canvas image.

```
function download() {
    var dt = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    this.href = dt;
};
```

I want to set the canvas background to `white` before downloading because on mobile, the images are very distorted and black. Any ideas?

Comment: `fillRect` ? But your problem is not that simple as you express it...

Comment: any hints on how I may be able to do it?

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far ?

Comment: This code that I am trying. It is downloading the image, but by default the background is transparent. I want to convert it to white.

Comment: And what efforts you have put to make it white ? Anything which did not work ?

Comment: I used `$('#canvas').css('background-color','#ffffff');` before downloading, but the image doesn't have a white background.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may want to draw a white rectangle the size of the entire canvas, beneath the actual content of the canvas.

```
// get the canvas 2d context
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

// set the ctx to draw beneath your current content
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-over';

// set the fill color to white
ctx.fillStyle = 'white';

// apply fill starting from point (0,0) to point (canvas.width,canvas.height)
// these two points are the top left and the bottom right of the canvas
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

You have to apply these lines before generating your toDataUrl() stream.

Idea taken from: http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2011/01/31/setting-the-background-color-when-generating-images-from-canvas-todataurl/

Comment: Worked like a charm.